# Is there a way to delete imageview and create it to show the picture in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a form where I capture a picture and show it in an imageview on android. Every time I clear the form and remove all views included in the imageview tag and try to recreate it, it doesn't show any picture. I'd like to know if there's a specific way to delete an imageview and create it again and keeps working fine.

I've tried to remove all views than every single view in the form but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imageView.setImageDrawable(null);` to clear Image from ImageView and set new Image.

Comment: I'm creating the imageview from code in my activity class when the user press add button and when he's done creating the object and send it to backend I clear the form removing all the views. The issue is when he creates another object,  the imageview doesn't show the picture captured from the camera.